# How to Get the BottomRightCell/TopLeftCell of a shape inside a group in Excel using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I have grouped a few shapes into a group. Let's call it Group1. I want to get the BottomRightCell/TopLeftCell of a particular shape, Shape1, in Group1. But whenever I run this code:

```
 ActiveSheet.Shapes("Group1").GroupItems("Shape1").BottomRightCell.Row
```

I get the row of the bottom right cell of the group instead of the particular shape1's bottom right cell. 
I also tried this:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Shape1").BottomRightCell.Row
```

Same thing happened. How do I get the Shape1's bottomrightcell even though it is grouped?

Comment: Not sure, but I think it's possible you might need to ungroup the shapes, get what you're after, and then regroup the shapes.

Comment: Logically, what you ask for shouldn't be possible. Excel's handbook says that grouping makes the shapes "be treated as a single object". Therefore the grouped shapes should have lost their individual relationship with the worksheet. Why do you want to move them individually after ensuring that they act like a group?

Comment: @Variatus IMHO what the OP asks for _should_ be possible.  Excel provides the `GroupItems` collection to access the individual shapes in a group.  For each item in `GroupItems` properties `Top` and `Left` report correctly, and can be modified to move individual group items.  It seems that for items in `GroupItems` `TopLeftCell ` and `BottomRightCell` are buggy and report on the group as a whole.

Comment: @chrisneilsen Ya, logically to me, i think the code should give me what I want but it is not the case.

Comment: @Variatus Can you give me a link to the handbook? Thanks!

Comment: @Mat'sMug I guess I have to use that way. Thanks!

Comment: This is where I got my wisdom from  :-)  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Group-or-ungroup-shapes-pictures-or-other-objects-A7374C35-20FE-4E0A-9637-7DE7D844724B#ID0EAABAAA=2010

Comment: @Chris Neilsen Are the Top and Left properties relative to the worksheet or relative to the canvas defined by the group?

Comment: @Variatus From my experience, it is relative to the canvas. E.g. 633.75 there will be decimal points

Comment: @Variatus to the worksheet canvas.  To relate back to TopLeftCell etc you would need to consider Height and Width of all cell above and to the left - very messy

Comment: @Variatus "After you make your group, you can still work with a single item in the group. Select the group, and then click the item to select it." In this sense, by referring to the single item in the group (kind of like .groupitems in vba), I should be able to work with that single item instead of the whole group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that for items in `GroupItems` `TopLeftCell`  and `BottomRightCell` are buggy and report on the group as a whole.

In contrast properties `Top` and `Left` report correctly for items in the `GroupItems` collection.

As a work-around consider this:

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim grp As Shape
    Dim shp As Shape, s As Shape
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set grp = ws.Shapes("Group 1") '<~~ update to suit
    With grp
        For Each shp In .GroupItems
            ' Create a temporary duplicate shape
            Set s = ws.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, shp.Left, shp.Top, shp.Width, shp.Height)

            ' Report the grouped shape to contrast the temporary shape result below
            Debug.Print shp.TopLeftCell.Row, shp.BottomRightCell.Row
            ' Report the duplicate shape to see correct location
            Debug.Print s.TopLeftCell.Row, s.BottomRightCell.Row

            ' Delete temporary shape
            s.Delete
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Here I create a duplicate of each shape in the `GroupItems` Collection outside the group and report its cell position.  Then delete the duplicate.

I've used Rectangles to demonstrate, but other shape type should be similar

Comment: It works! Although it is rather troublesome but I guess it's much better than having to ungroup them and group them again. Thanks for the creative way of solving this. You Rock!

Comment: Thanks @pomeloyou.  It's a PITA to _have_ to work around buggy properties, I thought it better to not mess with the original group itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement @MatsMug's solution with the following code sample.

Using the `Regroup` method after `Ungroup` creates a grouped `Shape` with a new name than the first one, so the code resets the new grouped `Shape` to have the original name:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim shpGrouped As Shape
    Dim strGroupShameName As String
    Dim lngGroupedShapeCount As Long
    Dim lngCounter As Long
    Dim strShapeArray() As String

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") '<~~ your sheet

    ' group
    Set shpGrouped = ws.Shapes("Group 7") '<~~ your grouped shape
    lngGroupedShapeCount = shpGrouped.GroupItems.Count
    strGroupShameName = shpGrouped.Name

    ' store child shapes in array
    ReDim strShapeArray(1 To lngGroupedShapeCount)
    For lngCounter = 1 To lngGroupedShapeCount
        strShapeArray(lngCounter) = shpGrouped.GroupItems(lngCounter).Name
    Next lngCounter

    ' ungroup
    shpGrouped.Ungroup

    ' report on shape locations
    For lngCounter = 1 To lngGroupedShapeCount
        Debug.Print ws.Shapes(strShapeArray(lngCounter)).TopLeftCell.Address
        Debug.Print ws.Shapes(strShapeArray(lngCounter)).BottomRightCell.Address
    Next lngCounter

    ' regroup and rename
    With ws.Shapes.Range(strShapeArray).Regroup
        .Name = strGroupShameName
    End With

End Sub
```